# How do I export an object from blender and import in Maya?

Tags: export

I need a way to export a specific model from my Blender scene (for example a textured table) and import it in an already created scene in Maya.

Example case to be more specific:

I created a classroom in Maya and a bedroom in Blender. I want to export the desk I created in Blender and import it as a desk in Maya. How can that be achieved?

Comment: Check out this link, see if it helps any: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X-izMDwkg7c

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way would be to select the object (desk) you want to export in Blender and export it as .obj file one of these ways:

- click File -> Export -> Wavefront (.obj) OR
- press space and type "export" -> click *Export Scene: Export OBJ*

Make sure to check **Selection Only** in the *Export OBJ* section, otherwise you would export the whole scene.

In Maya simply click

- File -> Import...

and select the exported file.