# How to properly export scene to 3ds Max?

Tags: objects, export, file-format, external-applications

How can I export 3D geometry object/scene, camera and textures to a .3DS format? I tried importing the file I created into 3DsMax but it didn't work properly.

Comment: I also tried with FBX, but weirdly it didnt worked at all :/

Comment: 3ds is a deprecated file format, not sure if autodesk yet support it. Try to export it as fbx - if that does not work immediately - play with the settings or try collada.

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/18395/how-do-i-export-an-object-from-blender-and-import-in-maya

Comment: @poor That's not really a duplicate, even though that answer might apply.  This question is not talking about motioon tracking, see [http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/q/549/5705](http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/q/549/5705).

Comment: @PGmath You are right, but the answers are the same and this should solve the issue. We can reopen it... if it's needed, right?

Comment: @poor But, as pretty much everybody in the linked meta post agreed, *duplicate answer doesn't mean duplicate question*!  I think this should definitely be reopened as it is a lot easier and less frustrating to get a direct answer to your own question than try to glean a solution from a question that is not really the same.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As of **Blender 2.8x** you can export your entire scene using [**Alembic**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.3ds) or [**USD**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FBX) *(Autodesk is working on adding USD support)*.

[image]
*Layout in Blender*

[image]
*Alembic file imported into 3ds Max 2019*

---

[**3ds**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.3ds) is a *deprecated file format*. For **Blender 2.7x** export your scene to **[FBX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FBX) 6.1 ASCII**, this should work immediately. In some cases you have to adjust the settings because it also depends on your *3ds Max* version and the version of the *fbx plugin* installed.

[image]
*Suzanne in Blender 2.73a*

[image]
*Suzanne in 3ds Max 2012*

#### Other options

- [**Collada** (.dae)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/COLLADA) - For instructions, see: [How to export a motion tracked camera to 3ds Max?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/23071)
- [**Wavefront** (.obj)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wavefront_.obj_file) - For exporting multiple obj files, see [Export multiple objects to .obj](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5382/export-multiple-objects-to-obj/31852#31852)

Comment: Sorry for didnt answer before, it worked as a .dae, so now i don't have any problems, thank you very much :)