# blender export to fbx with embed texture

Tags: texturing, export, image

I'm trying to export from blender to 3d max with textures.
I am exporting with .fbx format, but it only exports 4 textures. (in my .blend file I have 107 packed files)

My question is whether it is possible to get all the embedded images exported to fbx with textures?

I use blender 2.74 and exported to 3dmax 2015

Comment: the fbx exporter will only pack the textures that are used in the exported model.

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/24481/how-to-properly-export-scene-to-3ds-max/24527#24527