# MAX to blender conversion trouble

Tags: import, .fbx, conversion

I have a model of an oldtimer car that we're renovating. I'd like to try what colors we could use on the car and would like to do it in blender, but the model is in `.MAX`. I tried exporting it to FBX, but when I import it into blender, some of the car parts are rotated wrong and all the materials are black. Is there any way to solve this without having to manually re-create all of the stuff manually?

The .max model is created with V-Ray. I do have a trial version of 3DS Max, so I can re-export to DXF and can install a trial version of V-Ray if needed.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures/57541

Comment: Use Alembic: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/24527/31447 (working in both directions) However, you can not convert your materials easily from vray to cycles (different engines).

Comment: I have no idea of how 3dmax works... never opened it, but when you export from blender and you have this kind of errors, its usually because you have to apply transforms, and or modificators (if applicable)

Answer (score 0):

I do not know the exact procedure myself as I haven't used 3DS in years but many archviz people often haveg to export 3ds stuff with vray materials to Blender, and seem to have built quite a documentation around that specific issue.

The short version is:

1. convert all your vray materials to standard 3DS materials
2. Export into FBX or using a specific addons

Source:

- [ArchViz from V-Ray to Cycles (with tips) - Blender Tests - Blender Artists Community](https://blenderartists.org/t/archviz-from-v-ray-to-cycles-with-tips/1278868?u=l0lock)
- [V-ray 3Ds max to Cycles - Materials and Textures - Blender Artists Community](https://blenderartists.org/t/v-ray-3ds-max-to-cycles/1120005?u=l0lock)

In addition, before exporting anything, I highly advise checking what you are exporting is ready for it. Unnecessary modifiers collapsed and transforms applied.