# How export Blender files to 3DsMax with collection (keep layers)

Tags: export

I have a big scene in blender, with a lots of object, and i want export this to 3DsMax with the collections layers.

When i use FBX, and import in 3DsMax my file, in this last i don't recovery collections layers and it's a mess.

If someone have a idea for keep collections in fbx files, or other export files or maybe script ?
Keep hierarchy is important !
Thanks all.

PS : i use blender 2.81 or more and Max 2019

Comment: Try alembic: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/24527/31447

Comment: Thx but i use blender 2.81 or more and ASCII has been retired since 2.8, i can't export with this version.

Comment: Try Blender 2.82a, alembic and report back...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but. Blender's collections and 3DsMax layers doesn't work the same. If you want to keep your hierarcy when you transfer your models you should create parents, like your collections or you can try this addon. It creates parents from collections.

https://blendermarket.com/products/hierarchy-to-collections