# Exporting camera movement from Blender to Cinema 4D

Tags: export, camera, baking

So I have a very simple camera in Blender that I need to get into C4D. I've been trying both fbx and collada exports with various settings but nothing seems to go through. I either get no keyframes at all, or keyframes with scale and rotation completely wrong. I have baked the animation. Any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'd suggest try [Alembic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alembic_(computer_graphics)), I can not test it right now but it should work immediately: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/24527/

Comment: This works! Thank you so much.