# Blender to maya

Tags: export

Recently I work for a client who works on maya. He likes my work, done in blender he want the project file in .mb . Is there any way I can transfer my project all the shading texturing export to maya without losing the quality? Yes I can covert the file with fbx or obj formate but when I do that the texture is not appear only white shading please help me with that. I research all day could not find any solution, For single model exporting to obj works fine but in my case I have multiple object with hair particle and cant export the texture and shading and this drive me nuts please help me!!!

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/18395/ https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531

Comment: glTF may actually be a better option than fbx. In general the material nodes aren't portable to other software though and all exporters support at most a basic PBR setup with a single Principled BSDF and image textures.